# How can I set a php header redirect in a wordpress admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, header, postback

EDIT: I have expanded the example code to include a basic use case.

I am trying to make an admin page for a plugin in wordpress. I have succeeded in making a simple admin page using the instructions in the codex. However, I am currently stuck. I am trying to use a

```
header("Location: /myLocation");
```

call, but I can't set a header since apparantly by the time the admin page has been loaded, other HTML has already been output. I want to use a header redirect so that the form handler I am building for the admin page can use a POST to GET pattern. (postback the form to itself with post, process the post data, header redirect back to itself with get, so it prevents reposts and form resubmission warnings)

**Is there some way I can modify my set up so that I am able to make a call to `header()`?**

I followed the tutorial here
http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus

and here is my code, which is currently in a `mu-plugin`. Will making it a regular plugin have any affect on my ability to use `header()?` I'd rather stick with a `mu-plugin` if possible but would use a regular one if I had to.

Here's the code, everything works fine except the call to `header()`. Its just the sample given in the tutorial with some of my own text put in.

Thanks for reading!

```
<?php
/** Step 2 (from text above). */
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu');

/** Step 1. */
function my_plugin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('My Plugin Options', 'Manage Articles', 'manage_options', 'manageArticles', 'manage_articles');
}

/** Step 3. */
function manage_articles() {
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        wp_die(__('You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.'));
    }
?>

<?php

//this block of code is an example of what I am trying to do

if (isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit']==='true')
{
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("UPDATE myTable set name='{$_POST['something']}' where id='{$_POST['id']}'");
header("Location: manageArticles?updated");
}
if (isset($_GET['updated']))
{
echo "you have updated the table!";
}

    ?>
    My admin page
    <form name="theForm" action="" method="post">
        Something: <input type="text" value="something" name="something"><br>
        Row ID: <input type="text" value="1" name="id"><br>
        <input type="hidden" value="true" name="formSubmit">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You can always try to put `ob_start();` underneath your first `<?php`

Comment: the html that has already been output comes from the wordpress core, not from my page, so output buffering in my own script won't have any effect. I think I need to use a hook but I don't know much beyond that.

Comment: @chiliNUT why do you want a redirect in manage_articles? So if the user clicks on manage article menu what should it do ?

Comment: You'd have to register an action / hook callback (or whatever Wordpress calls them these days) for one of the early running actions, detect the condition that requires a redirect, then issue the *Location* header and exit.

Comment: @Sabari I have edited my question to include a use case.

Comment: @Phil do you know what action to hook into to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redircting to a page in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827795/redircting-to-a-page-in-php)

Comment: Those other questions describe the issue, that I am already aware of, without providing a solution specific to this use case. When I tail my error log I see that **headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/wordpress/wp-admin/menu-header.php:162)** so how can I hook into that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: Again, I know WHY I am getting the error, the question was WHERE is the initial output being generated so I can execute my header first.

Answer (score 1):

So... I still have more to learn about hooks. Since this is an `mu-plugin`, according to the list of admin hooks [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request), I can use the [muplugins_loaded hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/muplugins_loaded)

So put this at the top of the plugin

```
<?php
add_action('muplugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_override');

function my_plugin_override() {
    // your code here
    if (isset($_POST['formSubmit']) && $_POST['formSubmit'] === 'true') {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query("UPDATE myTable set name='{$_POST['something']}' where id='{$_POST['id']}'");
        header("Location: manageArticles?updated");
    }
    if (isset($_GET['updated'])) {
        echo "you have updated the table!";
    }
}
?>

<?php
//the rest of the code...
/** Step 2 (from text above). */
//......
```